# i don't know about this command that why it's not work even i install python propurelly, pip install virtualenv but didn't work "virtualenv env" this

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

virtualenv.exe env
virtualenv.exe : The term 'virtualenv.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- virtualenv.exe env
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

i want to create env environmemt for my new flask project

Comment: The simplest possible explanation is that you never installed this optional third-party command. If you did, we need to know from where, how, to where. But Python 3 ships with `py -m venv`; maybe use that instead?

Comment: Does this work by chance `python -m virtualenv env_name`?